# In R, auto.arima fails to capture seasonality

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

`auto.arima()` is giving me no seasonal component for my series, even though I can see that there is one present. The function gives me a non seasonal ARIMA model of order (5,0,0). So, when I try to forecast using that model, it just gives the mean. The time series is of daily minimum temperatures in Melbourne, Australia for ten years.

[Click this link to see the data and the auto.arima forecast](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IdiP0.png)

`

```
library(readr)

temp <- read_csv("~/Downloads/Melbourne Minimum Temp.csv", 
                 col_types = cols(Date = col_date(format = "%m/%d/%y"), 
                                  Temp = col_number()))

t <- ts(temp$Temp, start = temp$Date\[1], end = temp$Date[nrow(temp)])

auto.arima(t, trace = T)
```

`

Tried using the data as a ts object, as an xts object, and as a vector.

Comment: You should also post how you defined your time series. If auto.arima isn't detecting seasonality you may not have specified the correct frequency when you created your series. You can also use `auto.arima(...,D=1)` to force seasonal differencing.

Comment: I did not create the series; it's real data of minimum daily temperatures in Melbourne. I tried setting D=1, but that did not work.

Comment: If you want a useful answer you'll need to provide more information: this could be a subset of your data, but at the very least you should post your actual code that you used to produce that forecast. Especially the part where you defined your time series.

Comment: @RickArko I did not define the time series, I downloaded it [here](https://datamarket.com/data/set/2324/daily-minimum-temperatures-in-melbourne-australia-1981-1990#!ds=2324&display=line). If you can, download that data and try to use `auto.arima()` on it.

Comment: Can you post your exact code that you tried? `auto.arima()` requires your input to be of class `timeseries` which you need to define.

Comment: @RickArko Added the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just reporting a good well explained - as usual - blogpost by Rob Hyndman.

https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/dailydata/

The relevant part to your question says (blockquoting exactly the page):

> When the time series is long enough to take in more than a year, then
>   it may be necessary to allow for annual seasonality as well as weekly
>   seasonality. In that case, a multiple seasonal model such as TBATS is
>   required.

```
y <- msts(x, seasonal.periods=c(7,365.25))
fit <- tbats(y)
fc <- forecast(fit)
plot(fc)
```

> This should capture the weekly pattern as well as the longer annual
>   pattern. The period 365.25 is the average length of a year allowing
>   for leap years. In some countries, alternative or additional year
>   lengths may be necessary.

I think it does exactly what you want.

I also tried to simply create the time series with msts

```
y <- msts(x[1:1800], seasonal.periods=c(7,365.25))
```

(I cut the time series in half to be quicker)

and then run auto.arima() directly on it, forcing a seasonal component with D=1

```
fc = auto.arima(y,D=1,trace=T,stepwise = F)
```

it will take a while.. because I set stepwise = FALSE (if you want it to look at all combinations without shortcuts you can set approximation=FALSE as well)

```
Series: y 
ARIMA(1,0,3)(0,1,0)[365] 

Coefficients:
         ar1      ma1      ma2      ma3
      0.9036  -0.3647  -0.3278  -0.0733
s.e.  0.0500   0.0571   0.0405   0.0310

sigma^2 estimated as 12.63:  log likelihood=-3854.1
AIC=7718.19   AICc=7718.23   BIC=7744.54
```

and then the forecast

```
for_fc = forecast(fc)
plot(for_fc)
```

I am adding a figure with the complete time series (red) on top of the output of 
    plot(for_fc)
and it seems to work decently - but it was just a quick test.

[image]

Comment: Just randomly came back to this post after 3 years hahaha! Thanks for answering; it's funny that I switched to Python a few months after and have been using Python ever since :P